# What is wrong with my derivation of the general formula of the power series for $\cos^{2}(x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

I have arduously obtained the series for $\cos^2(x)$ by using long multiplication method (multiplying twice the Taylor series of $\cos(x)$ which is $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$
$$\cos^2(x)=1-x^2+\dfrac{1}{3}x^4-\dfrac{2}{45}x^6+\dfrac{1}{315}x^8+...$$

I wish to manipulate with the sigma notation to reduce the cost of labour, so I square the above general formula for $\cos(x)$:

$$\cos^2(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left(\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n!)}\right)^2=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{2n}x^{4n}}{[(2n)!]^2}$$

But this is plain wrong, the formula that I obtain is not the general formula for the series of $\cos^2(x)$.

So what is wrong with my manipulation with the sigma notation of this series. The power of $x$ and $-1$ is too high, it should be $2n$. Also, is my denominator correct?

How do you obtain the general formulae for this series?

Comment: Observe that if $a,b$ are general real numbers then $(a+b)^2\neq a^2+b^2$, giving $$\left(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n\right)^2 \neq \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n^2.$$

Comment: @OlivierOloa Don't understand what you are trying to say. Could you be more specific and answer in more detaisl? Thanks man! yes $a^{2}+b^2+2ab$ is greater or equal to $a^2+b^2$

Comment: @OlivierOloa How do you obtain the general formula for this series?

Comment: Maybe one may use $\cos^2x=\frac12+\frac12\cos 2x.$

Comment: @James Warthington A square of a sum is not equal to the sum of the squares!!!!!!!!

Comment: Hi James, to square a power series you need to take the [Cauchy product.](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/cauchy-product-of-power-series#:~:text=Theorem%201%20(The%20Cauchy%20Product,x%5En%20%5Cright%20)%24.)

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I don't know how to use Cauchy product to find the general formula for $cos^2(x)$

Comment: Although Teresa Lisbon's comment seems sensible, the comment of Olivier Oloa provides an elegant alternative.

Comment: @JamesWarthington I think it is quite complicated to use it, now that I see it. There's a formula to use it as shown in Wikipedia, so you can try to use that to calculate the first few terms. Clearly Oliver's method is better, it gives a general answer to each term of the expansion.

Comment: @JamesWarthington What the first comment is trying to say is that you made a mistake when you assumed $$\cos^2(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left(\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n!)}\right)^2$$ This is not true. If you are going to use the fact that $\cos(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$, you will find that $$\cos^2(x) = \left[\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right]^2$$ In other words, $$\left[\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right]^2 \neq \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left(\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n!)}\right)^2$$

Comment: @user516079 Very clear, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

When you square a summation in general, the result is *not* equal to the sum of the squares of each term of the summation, as you have assumed.

I will demonstrate this with a couple of examples. Firstly, it's clear that
$(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$. But according to what you wanted to do, then $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$, which is clearly wrong.

Similarly, consider the value of
$$\left(\sum_{r=1}^n 1\right)^2$$
This is clearly $(n)^2=n^2$, but according to what you're saying the value should be equal to
$$\sum_{r=1}^n 1^2=\sum_{r=1}^n 1=n$$
which again is clearly wrong.

Secondly, it's important to realize that $(n!)^2$ is **not** equal to $n^2!$. It cannot be simplified further I'm afraid; $(n!)^2$ is the best you can do. Again, verify this with some examples, eg $n=4$.

The best strategy to find the power series for your series is to utilise the double angle formulae, as Olivia Oloa has noted.

Firstly, recall that
$$\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1\implies\cos^2x=\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos2x)$$
Now, we know that
$$\cos2x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$
Hence,
$$\cos^2x=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @ALevelStudent  Thanks man, I got it. $a^2+b^2$ should be smaller or equal to $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2b$

Comment: @A-Level Student Excellent answer, like many of your others.

Comment: @K.defaoite thank you so much for your comment, I can't tell you how much I appreciate it and how happy it makes me!

Comment: @K.defaoite I approved your comment :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you so much!! I am really touched by you and K.defaoite's kindness.

Comment: ahahahah ...but it is true.....

Comment: @JamesWarthington $a^2 +b^2$ is smaller or equal to $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$ provided that $2ab\geq 0$ which of course is not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

Since your error was already explained in other answers let us see what one obtains if the series multiplication in your example is applied correctly. We have:

$$\begin{align}\cos^2 x&=\left[\sum_{i\ge0}(-1)^i\frac{x^{2i}}{(2i)!}\right]^2\\
&=\sum_{j\ge0}\sum_{i\ge0}(-1)^{i+j}\frac{x^{2i+2j}}{(2i)!(2j)!}\\
&=\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}\sum_{i\ge0}\frac{(2k)!}{(2i)!(2k-2i)!}\\
&=\frac12+\frac12\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^k\frac{(2x)^{2k}}{(2k)!}\\
&=\frac{1+\cos2x}2,
\end{align}$$
where the proof of
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{(2k)!}{(2i)!(2k-2i)!}
=\begin{cases}1,& k=0,\\
2^{2k-1},& k>0
\end{cases}
$$
is left to you.