# Is it possible to find the closed form for this series $\frac{(-1)^{2n}x^{4n}}{[(2n)!]^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

In [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4004044/what-is-wrong-with-my-derivation-of-the-general-formula-of-the-power-series-for?noredirect=1#comment8264466_4004044), I made a basic mistake of expanding series for $\cos^2(x)$:

$$\cos^2(x)\neq \color{red}{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left(\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n!)}\right)^2=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{2n}x^{4n}}{[(2n)!]^2}}$$

I wonder what is the function to which the above series converge if it is not $\cos^{2}(x)$. Is it possible to find its closed form?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you’re summing over integers, the $(-1)^{2n}$ factor is just equal to $1$. Plugging the series into WolframAlpha then gives the result as a sum of Bessel functions ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum+x%5E%284n%29%2F%28%282n%29%21%29%5E2+from+n%3D0+to+infinity+)).

Answer (score 1):

This is
$$
\frac{J_0(2x)+I_0(2x)}2
$$
where $J_0(x)$ and $I_0(x)$ are [Bessel and modified Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Definitions) of the first kind, respectively.

Comment: Man, just one mistake and that leads to a completely different result. Thanks!